# What is a 4x 10gbe QSFP-QSFP cable?

Tags: networking, hardware, cable, 10gbethernet, infiniband

I was looking for QSFP cables on Ebay and came across a `Brocade 58-0000033-01` marked as `4x 10GE` even though it has one QSFP connector on each end. I don't understand what this cable is for, will it work with a 10GBE/40GB Infiniband HCA?

[image: cable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QSFP means, literally, "Quad SFP" connector. In other words, it is a single SFP connector that carries **four** link.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QSFP):

> The Quad Small Form-factor Pluggable (QSFP) is a compact,
>   hot-pluggable transceiver used for data communications applications...
>   It is an industry format jointly developed and supported by many
>   network component vendors, allowing data rates from 4x1 Gb/s for QSFP
>   and 4x10 Gbit/s for QSFP+

From the same page, you can read that a QSFP+ connector *should* support QDR Infiniband. That said, I would really check with my HBA vendor for compatibility.

Comment: Thank you, that's very logical. I guess I was thinking the "Q" mean "for QDR".